# About idempotent algebra and graded idempotent algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

I recently saw (e.g. in [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.03513.pdf)) the notions of idempotent algebra and graded idempotent algebra, however there were no definitions for these notions.
I saw in another [paper](https://math.colorado.edu/%7Ekearnes/Papers/simfix.pdf) stating that:

> "An algebra is idempotent if each of its fundamental operations is idempotent."

From my point of view, this definition seems very strange but I am afraid that I am missing something.

Can someone clarify this notions and perhaps give a non-trivial examples for both notions.

Thanks in advance.